# Uncaught ReferenceError: docuSignClick is not defined

Tags: docusignapi

Trying to embed elastic template agreement into my application, but it is not rendering and I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: docuSignClick is not defined, despite the "script src="https://stage.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js" being there.

Note that the application in question is PTC's Thingworx, but using a custom extension to add the javascript required.

Tried having the reference to the docusign library just before the div, as suggested in the following article [Embed elastic template](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/how-to/embed-elastic-templates/?_gl=1*1hwrden*_ga*MTQwODU5NDk3NC4xNjkzNDg1Njgy*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTY5MzgzNjE1Ny4xMi4xLjE2OTM4MzcyNjYuNjAuMC4w&_ga=2.24307378.960760792.1693816264-1408594974.1693485682), as well as in the head of the page, to ensure the library is definitely loaded first. I can also see the library is loaded fine when viewing the Sources tab in Developer tools in Chrome.

Either way I see this docuSignClick is not defined error and therefore it won't render the agreement. At this stage I'm purely just trying to render the agreement from the URL acquired from the API using postman.

```
<div class="widget-content widget-flexcontainer widget-container responsive tw-flex-row" id="root_navigationfunction-463-popup_flexcontainer-46" style="flex-flow: row; align-items: flex-end; place-content: flex-start flex-end;">
    <div id="ds-terms-of-service"></div>
    <script>docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({ agreementUrl: "" }, "#ds-terms-of-service");</script>
</div>
```

This is taken directly from the source of the page. I removed the agreement Url on purpose for this post.
*Note that the library is in the head of the page in this example

Update 06-09-23:

I have managed to get rid of the reference error by adding the js reference back into the content and removing the second set of script tags, however it still will not render on the page:

```
<div class="widget-content widget-flexcontainer widget-container responsive tw-flex-row" id="root_navigationfunction-463-popup_flexcontainer-46" style="flex-flow: row; align-items: flex-end; place-content: flex-start flex-end;">
<div id="ds-terms-of-service"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js">
    docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({ agreementUrl: "" }, "#ds-terms-of-service");
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML/JavaScript that you should have and I just tried and it's working just fine.
What you may want to try is download the [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/), which runs this code (you can pick from a variety of coding langs) and see if that works (that's how I run it). Then see how it's different than your code.

(Note `@ViewBag.AgreementUrl` is because this is part of a C#/ASP.NET code, but this is the URL you get when you make a REST API call to the Click API to get the embedded URL for this elastic template)

```
<div id="ds-terms-of-service"></div>
<script src="https://stage.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js"></script>
<script>
    docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
        agreementUrl: "@ViewBag.AgreementUrl",
        onAgreed: function () {
            // Triggered if the user has just agreed
            document.getElementById("agreementStatus").innerHTML = "Agreed";
        }
    }, "#ds-terms-of-service");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I already have this correct:

Comment: Try to change https://stage.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js to https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js

Comment: tried this as well, no luck. I have also now downloaded the JS file and included a relative path to it, rather than using the link URL and that also did not work.

Comment: May need to work with our developer support team, I don't know why it's not working for you. Maybe something in your network is blocking downloading JS from a different domain? That's the only thing I can think of, some IT default settings for your browser or a firewall etc.